# Subjuntivo imperfecto (use/usara)

Tags: subjuntivo

¿Qué diferencia hay entre las siguientes expresiones?

> — para que lo **use**.
>    — para que lo **usara**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviamente la diferencia en esos ejemplos es el tiempo verbal.

> [...] para que lo **use**.

es **presente** de subjuntivo, mientras que

> [...] para que lo **usara**.

es **pretérito imperfecto** (luego, tiempo pasado). Digamos que alguien te pregunta por el coche que le has prestado a un amigo que lo necesita.

> [Sí, le dejé el coche] para que lo **use**.

El tiempo presente nos dice que tu amigo todavía dispone del coche y piensa usarlo en el futuro cercano. En cambio

> [Sí, le dejé el coche] para que lo **usara**.

indica que la acción de tu amigo de usar el coche pertenece al pasado. Quizá te lo ha devuelto o no, pero ese tiempo verbal indica que **el el pasado** tu le dejaste el coche, para que él hiciera uso de él. Compara

> Sí, le dejé el coche para que lo **use**, así que puede tenerlo el tiempo que quiera.
>
> Sí, le dejé el coche para que lo **use**. Ya me lo devolverá cuando termine de necesitarlo.
>
> Sí, le dejé el coche para que lo **use**. Así que si le ves conduciéndolo, no es que lo haya robado. Se lo he prestado.
>
> Sí, le dejé el coche (hace un mes) para que lo **usara** (quizá por un día o dos) y todavía no me lo ha devuelto.

Comment: Se usa bastante el imperfecto de subjuntivo, pero siempre lo uso en con cordancia con el pasado de indicativo. Como nativo, lo entiendo pero nunca me había puesto a analizar qué significado real tenía. Es simple entender el presente de subjuntivo pero no así el imperfecto. Cuando leí que la *acción de usar pertenece* al pasado, me quedó clara la distinción entre *no sé si lo **usó**, o no.*